# RESTAPI and Twilio signed with StrongName

Tags: c#, vb.net, twilio

I'm trying to add Twilio and RESTApi into my signed Visual Studio project.
When I compile, VS told me it's not possible to link not-signed DLL's into the project.

So, I followed some instructions to ILDASM, sign and ILASM these DLL's with no errors at all (see http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/ViewCE64BEF3-51A6-4F1C-90C9-6A76B015C9FB.htm). But, when I run the application, VS stops in the Twilio call and informs: "Twilio cannot load RestApi or any of its dependencies because they are not strongname signed".

The Twilio source-code at GitHub does not compile in my VS2013 if I sign the project - perhaps because RESTApi within this source is not signed too. The problem is about RESTApi source-code is not present in the Twilio package.

SO, how can I add these DLL's in my project since I cannot delete the strongname signature from it?

Thanks for nay help!

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

IIRC there is a seperate signed version of RestSharp on NuGet that you could use.  Not sure how up to date it is though, but the Twilio library doesn't use any new features of RestSharp.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Devin, thank you for your prompt answer. How can I access this version since I had no access to IIRC? And thanks again for your help. Best regards!

Comment: Thanks Devin, I found a version of RestSharp signed into NuGet.  But unfortunetely, when I compile project and run it, VS informs to me that Twilo cannot find the 1.5.0 version of RestSharp - even the signed library being referenced into VS project. I guess it's because the signed RestSharp has "100.0.0" in the version field.  I'll continue trying a solution here...

Comment: Did you actually remove the existing RestSharp nuget package and then install the signed one?  Not sure why VS would complain about wanting 105 if you've removed it.

Comment: Well, at least from the References Tab I had manually removed the older RestSharp and put the new one. The Build process occurr normally but, when I execute the code, VS stops right in the Twilio load and emits the message above. But I really didn't proceed with any NuGet uninstall.

Comment: I beleive you'll need to uninstall the existing unsigned RestSharp through NuGet otherwise the package restore will automatically put it back.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it tomorrow. Thanks again for the whole support Devin!